# I can't access object properties that are inside an object in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an object named contact. When I logged the content of this object as `console.log(contact)` I get the following contents

```
addresss:[]
company:""
emails:[]
id:3
internet_calls:[]
lat:"10.115730000000001"
lng:"76.461445"
name:"Diji  "
phones:[]
special_days:[]
timestamp:1508919658000
title:"Mr"
websites:[]
__proto__:Object
```

But when i tried to log the length of addresss field by `console.log(contact.addresss.length)` I get `undefined`

When I logged the object as `console.log(JSON.stringify(contact))` I get the following result

```
{"id":3,"title":"Mr","name":"Diji  ","company":"","lat":"10.115730000000001","lng":"76.461445","timestamp":1508919658000,"phones":[],"emails":[]}
```

so my question is why some of the properties of my object is not showing in later log but show up in first log?

Comment: are you changing the contact object  before the second log?

Comment: how does android tag comes here :O

Comment: No I am not changing contact object before second log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log object via `console.log`, the value shown in the console will not be the same as in time of that call, but rather the last value by the time you see it. This is caused by passing object as a reference.

When you log the JSON representation, you log simple string, which is passed by value, so you see the value as it was in the time of call.

So the answer is, that the `addresss` array is probably added later that you are expecting. Btw `address` spells with double `s`, not triple :]

Btw same applies to those object fields, that are also not present in the JSON: `internet_calls`, `special_days`, `websites`.

Comment: How can you know this based on him giving no implementation? If his implementation is just a `*.ts` file with the object and the two console statements then it would work. What am I missing that allowed you to answer this?

Comment: Well I suppose that the `console.log(contact)` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(contact))` are in the same place. Then this is the only answer that could cause this behavior. It's just common misunderstanding of how `console.log` works.

Comment: I guess I'm still not getting it. If you create a single TypeScript file, create an object such as this, then run all three `console.log` statements that the OP mentions then nothing would be undefined. Is this the only case where these things line up to produce his answer and you know it from experience or is there something I can learn? Please don't misunderstand. I am not suggesting you are wrong. I just don't see what you see and want to learn. Thanks.

Comment: Well this problem is about object mutation, of course there are too few information to be sure, but I ran to this issue many times. If you want to know the exact data in time of using `console.log`, you need to use some scalar value, just like JSON string, that will be preserved by the time goes.

Comment: Objects are passed as reference in javascript, so the mutation can be caused by any service or component that has reference to that object.

Comment: I got the content when I put a delay of one second by `setTimeout(()=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(contact))},1000);

Comment: So you are probably populating that object in some async callback, but expecting the values to be there before the callback ends.